# What are the differences between InheritsFrom and the is operator?

Tags: delphi

In all cases I can remember, the following instructions give the same result:

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TObject);
  TMyChildClass = class(TMyClass);

var
  MyObj : TMyChildClass;

procedure TForm1.Test();
var
  ResultA : Boolean;
  ResultB : Boolean;
begin
  //Using TObject.InheritsFrom
  ResultA := MyObj.InheritsFrom(TMyClass);

  //Using 'is' operator
  ResultB := MyObj is TMyClass;

  //Showing results
  ShowMessage(
    'InheritsFrom = ' + BoolToStr(ResultA, True) + sLineBreak +
    'is = ' + BoolToStr(ResultB, True)
  );
end;
```

Is there some difference in using the `is` operator instead of `TObject.InheritsFrom` function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `is` operator is built on top of `InheritsFrom`. So,

```
obj is TSomeClass
```

is implemented as

```
(obj <> nil) and obj.InheritsFrom(TSomeClass)
```

The expression `obj.InheritsFrom(TSomeClass)` is perhaps a little confusing because it looks like `InheritsFrom` is an instance method. In fact `InheritsFrom` is a class method, and the runtime class of `obj` is passed to `InheritsFrom` as the `Self` pointer.

So fundamentally `is` and `InheritsFrom` perform the same task, at least when restricting attention to classes. Note that `is` is more general and can also be used with interfaces, for example.

There are obvious syntactical differences. Namely that `is` requires an instance, whereas `InheritsFrom` is a class function. Although, as we have seen, the Delphi language does support calling class functions on instance references. And the other obvious difference is that `is` has a built-in test for a `nil` reference.

These are just syntactical differences though, the fundamental operation is the same, as evidenced by the fact that `is` calls `InheritsFrom`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a difference. `InheritsFrom` is class function and it's primary purpose is testing whether class `IS` (inherits from some class).

You cannot use `is` operator on classes.

`TMyChildClass is TMyClass` would not compile, but you can use `TMyChildClass.InheritsFrom(TMyClass)` instead.

Comment: Even though there is a slight difference between the two, we should not ignore the fact that they do have similarities.

Comment: In that sense I mean on some scenarios they can achieve same results!

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to mention at least one case where

```
obj is TSomeClass
```

operator doesn't behave exactly as

```
(obj <> nil) and obj.InheritsFrom(TSomeClass)
```

When the compiler "thinks" that obj can only be a TSomeClass member, it will skip the TObject.InheritsFrom() call (when using the *is* operator) and only test for a nil pointer. This can be confirmed by the following test code (tested in 10.2.3 Tokyo and 10.3.3 Rio):

```
procedure TestForTStringList(obj: TStringList);
begin
  if obj.InheritsFrom(TStringList) then
  begin
    //
  end;

  if obj is TStringList then
  begin
    //
  end;
end;
```

This code produces the following assembly code

[image]

In this method, we can see that obj.InheritsFrom() actually calls TObject.InheritsFrom() method. On the other hand, the code related to the *is* operator only checks for a nil pointer.

Compare with the code generated by the compiler for an *is* operator when the class can't be determined at compile time:

[image]

Above, the variable was declared as TObject, so the compiler actually calls System.IsClass(), which is:

```
function _IsClass(const Child: TObject; Parent: TClass): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Child <> nil) and Child.InheritsFrom(Parent);
end;
```

You may think that this doesn't make any difference, but it does in some specific debugging scenarios: When using FastMM and the option to check for method calls on a freed object is checked. In this case, FastMM replaces the actual object with a TFreedObject instance.

In this case when obj is actually a TFreedObject instance (not a TStringList).

```
obj.InheritsFrom(TStringList) = False
```

On the other hand

```
(obj is TStringList) = True
```

because the code will actually only check for a nil pointer.

PS: the generated code is the same regardless of compiler optimization settings